# How do I create an If Then statement. If column x is nan then nan column y

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using the following line to turn any value that is `0` to `nan` in my `Flow Rate` column.  This is to help with averaging later on.

```
df['Flow Rate (gpm)'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

I would like to build on this by writing another line that recognizes when my flow rate is `nan` then my pressure should be `nan` as well.  Currently I am getting the following

[image]

I tried this

```
df['Injection Pressure (psi)'] = df['Injection Pressure (psi)'].mask(df['Injection Pressure (psi)'] < 0)
```

There are unfortunately several scenarios that this does not work for.

Comment: use `numpy.where()`?

Comment: what `scenarios` do you mean? We can't see your full code, we can't run it, we can't use data from image (because Python can't load image to get data), and we can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Maybe better create `minimal working code` with example data directly in code (as `DataFrame(...)`) so we could simply copy and run it. You could also show what you get for example data, and what you expected for example data.

Comment: maybe you should first create mask `mask = (df['Flow Rate (gpm)'] == 0)` and later use it with other columns. `df['Injection Pressure (psi)'][mask] = np.nan`. And later replace `nan` in `'Flow Rate (gpm)'`  - `df['Flow Rate (gpm)'][mask] = np.nan`

Comment: Use `df['Injection Pressure (psi)']] = df['Injection Pressure (psi)']].mask(df['Flow Rate (gpm)'].isna(), np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

Use .loc [row, column]. You can use logical indexing along with pd.isnull to obtain the rows where flow rate is NaN. Column is of course pressure.

```
df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Flow Rate (gpm)']), 'Injection Pressure (psi)'] = np.nan
```

As another comment pointed out, you could use numpy alternatively. np.where arguments are (series conditional, value if true, value if false)

```
df['Injection Pressure (psi)'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['Flow Rate (gpm)']), df['Injection Pressure (psi)'], np.nan)
```

These both work:

Input:

```
   Flow Rate (gpm)  Injection Pressure (psi)
0              5.0                       1.1
1              4.3                       3.1
2              NaN                       4.0
3              2.0                       1.3
4              NaN                       0.0
```

Output for both solutions:

```
   Flow Rate (gpm)  Injection Pressure (psi)
0              5.0                       1.1
1              4.3                       3.1
2              NaN                       NaN
3              2.0                       1.3
4              NaN                       NaN
```